# using use_in field option with ModelResource in django tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm a little confused about the difference between `Resource` and `ModelResource` in django tastypie.

I have a `Resource`

```
class ReportResource(ModelResource):
  class Meta:
     queryset = Report.objects.filter(deleted__isnull=True)
     resource_name = 'report'
     object_class = Report
```

When retrieving a list the field `report_data` should not be fetched ....

**Is it possible to use the [`use_in`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in) option in a `ModelResource` ?**

One alternative is using the `full_dehydrate` :

```
def full_dehydrate(self, bundle, for_list=False):   

    if for_list:
        # List view
        # Remove unnecessary fields from the bundle 

    # Detail view
    return super(ReportResource,self).full_dehydrate(bundle,for_list)
```

But removing the fields in dehydrate might cause poor performance since all the fields has already been fetched from the db.

**EDIT**

I'll explain further what i'm trying to achieve

When retrieving a **list** of reports using `api/report/` I want to get a json array containing only the `name` and `description` of the report object.

When retrieving a **single** report using `api/report/88387` I want to get a json containing all the fields in the model.

This is possible in the `full_dehydrate` function as explained above but in my opinion there must a built in solution. The [`use_in`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#use-in) attribute of Resource Field seems like a good solution but i'm not sure how i can use it with a `ModelResource`.

There is an old issue on [github](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/18) about this and i was wondering if there is a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass the `__init__` function in your ReportResource and set the `use_in` flag there, now that your fields have been populated:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Call the object's parent, which will set up and populate
    # the Resource fields from the queryset provided
    super(ReportResource, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Now loop through the fields of the resource, and when we
    # find the one we only want to be shown in the detail view,
    # set its use_in attr appropriately
    for field_name, field_object in self.fields.items():
        if field_name == 'report_data':
            field_object.use_in = 'detail'
```

(Generically, you could have this in a separate class that you mix in, and perhaps it could read the list of what you want from a variable in Meta, but this should do what you ask.)

The same sort of loop through `self.fields.items()` is used for the `use_in` check in Resource's full_dehydrate method, as you can see from the [source code of `resources.py`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L817).

Comment: I actually havent had time to test this yet but you backed your answer with code so I wont let this points go to waste. Thanks !

Comment: Is this a work around or is this how it is supposed to be done? As per the documentation, just adding use_in in the resource should do the trick however it doesn't specify if it will work for ModelResource or not?

Comment: You presumably aren't specifying the fields if you're using a ModelResource, so there's nothing to use `use_in` on :) In which case, the way I describe is a way to do it, it's not a "workaround" in that sense. If you specified fields, you could presumably use `use_in` on them.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you can use use_in in the ModelResource.

ModelResource is Tastypie's "contrib" resource.

The ModelResource calls Resource's full_dehydrate method in the following methods:

[get_list, get_detail, post_list, put_list, put_detail, patch_list, patch_detail and get_multiple]

In each _list method the full_dehydrate method is called with the for_list=True and in each _detail method the full_dehydrate method is not called with the for_list (for_list=False is default)

When defining fields in your resource just add the use_in attribute ("all", "detail", "list") for each field that needs special attention, default is "all".

The usage of this attribute is in the full_dehydrate method.
It skips dehydration for fields not matching the use_in attribute along side the for_list param.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't define any fields in my resource. it's a `ModelResource`. This is exactly my problem